# Dragging a image in flex

Tags: apache-flex

Hi I am having trouble in dragging a image within a loader. I am able to do
zooming and rotating image but not moving image with mouse. Purpose is when I
zoom a image info is out of boundaries and so is hidden. To see that info users
should be able to drag the image any way they want. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if I understood what you're trying to do, but take a look on this adobe pan/zoom component and see if that's what you were looking for
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/samples/fig_panzoom/